# Word_Search Generator doesn't complete the word

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to create a word search generator, and for some reason, my code breaks once the word is over 5 characters long. One interesting thing is that after the word exceeds 5 letters, it'll start deleting the 5th letter and onwards (prints 'abcde', after that, at 6 characters long, 'abcd', then 'abc'). Can you help spot the problem with the loop?

```
def create_board():
    board = [[]for _ in range(10)]
    for a in range(len(board)):
        for b in range(10)):
            board[a].append("")
    return board

board = create_board()

def add_word_horizontal_forward(word,board):
    word_list = list(word)
    num_row = randrange(len(board))
    start = 0
    for b in range(int(config[0])-len(word_list)):
        if board[num_row][start + b] == "":
            if b <= len(word_list)-1:
                board[num_row][start + b] = word_list[b]
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
            start = start + len(word_list) -1 
            if start > len(board[num_row]) - len(word_list):
                return -1
    return board

print(add_word_horizontal_forward("abcdefg",board)
```

Here is a quick rundown of the code: I have a nested list, and the function is going check first if the place that it wants to put down is actually an empty list, and if it is, then put the letter down; if it isn't, then change the starting position the next place (which is the position that is the length of the board -1. However, it just wouldn't work, and I have checked that the initial board is correct and wouldn't run-off.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? What's a word search generator? Apologies for my ignorance. Literal actual/expected output would be helpful for me.

Comment: A word search is a game where there are hidden words among a board full of letter, search up online for more information. The goal for this right now to too see letters generated and arranged in a correct order

Comment: I'd recommend editing the post to show the exact output. Expecting folks to infer your desired behavior makes it very difficult to answer the question. Thanks.